# ASP.NET/VB.NET/SQL Server 2012 - Page keeps loading

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to run this code, and whenever I press the 'Register' button, nothing is happening (the page is like loading but stays on the same page)

Code:

```
 Public Sub register()



    Dim Username As String = txtUsername.Text
    Dim Surname As String = txtSurname.Text
    Dim Password As String = txtPassword.Text
    Dim Name As String = txtName.Text
    Dim Address1 As String = txtAddress1.Text
    Dim Address2 As String = txtAddress2.Text
    Dim City As String = txtCity.Text
    Dim Email As String = txtEmail.Text
    Dim Country As String = drpCountry.Text
    Dim DOB As Date = calDOB.SelectedDate
    Dim Occupation As String = txtOccupation.Text
    Dim WorkLocation As String = txtWorkLocation.Text
    Dim Age As Integer = Date.Today.Year - calDOB.SelectedDate.Year


    Dim ProjectManager As String = "N/A"
    Dim TeamLeader As String = "N/A"
    Dim TeamLeaderID As Integer = "1"
    Dim ProjectManagerID As Integer = "1"

    Dim RegistrationDate As Date = DateTime.Today
    Dim ContractType As String = "N/A"
    Dim ContractDuration As Integer = 6
    Dim Department As String = "N/A"

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim registerSQL As SqlCommand
    Dim sqlComm As String

    Dim validateSQL As SqlCommand

    Dim sqlValidate As String

    sqlValidate = "SELECT * FROM users  where username=" + txtUsername.Text.ToString

    sqlComm = "INSERT INTO users(Username, Password, Name, Surname, Address1, Address2, " +
        "City, Country, date_of_birth, age, Occupation, department, work_location, " +
        "project_manager,team_leader, team_leader_id, project_manager_id, " +
        "date_registration, contract_type, contract_duration) " +
        "VALUES(@p1, @p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14,@p15," +
        "@p16,@p17,@p18,@p19,@p20)"

    conn.Open()

    validateSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlValidate, conn)
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = validateSQL.ExecuteReader()

    If dr.HasRows = False Then


        validateSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlValidate, conn)
        validateSQL.CommandText = sqlValidate

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = validateSQL.ExecuteReader()
        reader.Read()

        registerSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlComm, conn)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Username)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Password)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Name)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", Surname)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", Address1)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", Address2)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", City)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", Country)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", DOB)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", Age)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", Occupation)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p12", Department)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p13", WorkLocation)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p14", ProjectManager)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p15", TeamLeader)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p16", TeamLeaderID)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p17", ProjectManagerID)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p18", RegistrationDate)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p19", ContractType)
        registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p20", ContractDuration)

        registerSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

        conn.Close()

    ElseIf dr.HasRows = True Then


        lblUsername.Text = "That Username (" + txtUsername.Text + ") is already registered/taken."
        lblUsername.Visible = True
        conn.Close()

    End If


End Sub
```

Button event handler:

```
Protected Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click

    register()


End Sub
```

Is something wrong with the code?

Comment: Which code calls  this sub? This is not an event handler and you haven't show the code that handles the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9ttex.aspx)

> While the SqlDataReader is being used, the associated SqlConnection is
>   busy serving the SqlDataReader, and no other operations can be
>   performed on the SqlConnection other than closing it. This is the case
>   until the Close method of the SqlDataReader is called. For example,
>   you cannot retrieve output parameters until after you call Close.

It appears that you have the SqlDataReader open when you try to execute the insert command.
I will try to close it before using the insert command

```
If dr.HasRows = False Then
    dr.Close()

    ' The following lines are probably a remainder of a copy/paste operation'
    ' They are not needed and you should remove them'

    'validateSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlValidate, conn)'
    'validateSQL.CommandText = sqlValidate'
    'Dim reader As SqlDataReader = validateSQL.ExecuteReader()'
    'reader.Read()'

    ' Now execute the insert command
```

Also your command to check for the user presence, apart from perfomance arguments, is wrong because introduces  Sql Injection possibilities.

Summarizing try with these changes....

```
 sqlValidate = "SELECT * FROM users  where username=@uname"
 validateSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlValidate, conn)
 validateSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtUserName.Text)
 Dim dr As SqlDataReader = validateSQL.ExecuteReader()
 Dim userFound = dr.HasRows
 dr.Close()
 if userFound = False then
    ......
```

Comment: So I removed the extra open connections, now I'm getting another error in `validateSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlValidate, conn)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = validateSQL.ExecuteReader()
        conn.Close()` the error being: Invalid column name 'cdarwin'. (where cdarwin is the username entered in the username textbox)

Comment: No `conn.Close()`, this shuts down the connection, it is the DataReader that you need to close `dr.Close()`....

Comment: Invalid column name because you don't use the parameters (and in your original command you have forgotten the single quotes)

Comment: Ok thanks! Do you know why it is giving me that error because of this: `sqlValidate = "SELECT * FROM users  where username=" + txtUsername.Text.ToString`

Comment: The error being `Invalid column name 'cdarwin'.` (where cdarwin is the username entered in the username textbox